# How can I change a search provider's URL in IE8?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, google-search

Now that Google finally allows searching over HTTPS, I switched all my browsers to use https://google.com by default (I documented my effort in [my blog](http://www.guyvider.com/2010/05/secure-google-search.html)). The only browser I couldn't change the URL string in, is IE8. You can either add, remove, or change the priority of a search provider - as far as I've seen.

Can anyone suggest a way to change the default search behavior in E8 to go to HTTPS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to check out [this site.](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/13/how-to-create-your-own-search-provide-in-internet-explorer-8/) It will show you how to create your own search engine plugins.

Comment: Good idea! It works. Will update my blog post. Thanks!